# Joomla 3 - Return raw data from controller task

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-task

Can someone tell me the correct way to return raw data without html from a task in my component?

I've tried `index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=mysubcontroller.mytask&format=raw` and `index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=mysubcontroller.mytask&tmpl=component`

But everything returns with html.

Can't seem to find anything written down anywhere to address this, which seems to be a recurring theme for me with Joomla!

Hope someone can help as I've had to create a new template called `raw.php` with only the jdoc include tag and call it like so:

`index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=mysubcontroller.mytask&tmpl=raw`

That's a hack as far as I'm concerned because it is not a solution that is self contained within the component.

Hope someone can enlighten me.

Many thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've found out a little more about how to .

After a bit of searching on Stack Overflow, I found this which allows you to output just JSON:

[Joomla Controller Task that returns JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739800/joomla-controller-task-that-returns-json-data?rq=1)

I feel a bit foolish for not seeing this before.  Does anyone know if using `JFactory::getApplication()->close();` will work with anything other than JSON?